# Center textPath make text upside down

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to center vertically and horizontally a text inside an arc path but after add `startOffset="50%"`, it turned upside down.

```css
text a {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 42px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  fill: #FF9800;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1277 224">
  <path id="curve" d="M640 224c347.406 0 640-142 640-142V0S995 142.5 640 142.5 0 0 0 0v82s292.595 142 640 142Z"></path>
  <text text-anchor="middle">
      <textPath xlink:href="#curve" startOffset="50%">
        <a xlink:href="#item-1">Item 1</a>
        <a xlink:href="#item-2">Item 2</a>
        <a xlink:href="#item-3">Item 3</a>
        <a xlink:href="#item-4">Item 4</a>
      </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

**Update**

I fixed the orientation issue but now I need to center vertically the text inside the arc.

https://codepen.io/marcelo2605/pen/yLoNdeg?editors=1100

**Fixed!**

I wrapped all the `<a>` tags with `<tspan dy="25%">`.

Comment: If the text isn't in the path: just reverse the direction that your path is drawn. If you do that, the text will be on the other side of the line.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the problem is that your `path` begins in the lower center. If it would start in the upper center your code would work.

But you could split the `textPath` in two and define the `startOffset` different:

```css
text a {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 42px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  fill: #FF9800;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1277 224">
  <path id="curve" d="M640 224c347.406 0 640-142 640-142V0S995 142.5 640 142.5 0 0 0 0v82s292.595 142 640 142Z"></path>
  <text text-anchor="middle">
      <textPath xlink:href="#curve" startOffset="96%">
        <a xlink:href="#item-1">Item 1</a>
        <a xlink:href="#item-2">Item 2</a>
      </textPath>
      <textPath xlink:href="#curve" startOffset="5%">
        <a xlink:href="#item-3">Item 3</a>
        <a xlink:href="#item-4">Item 4</a>
      </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```